# How to show and hide an activity's ProgressBar from a AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-progressbar

I have a created a separate class which extends AsyncTask which i am using for communication in my whole app. Every activity of my class uses this AsyncTask class for communication. I want to show ProgressBar (activity indicator) whenever communication is in progress. If i show and hide ProgressBar in activity which uses communication class then ProgressBar freezes until communication is done. Is there any way to show a ProgressBar in middle of screen from AsyncTask class so it doesn't freeze and user knows that there is something going on in background. I am using following code:

```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity {

      ProgressBar spinner;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);

         spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.Id.progressbar); 
         spinner.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
      }

      protected void onResume()
      {
         super.onResume();
      }

      public void buttonClickHandler(View target){
         try{
            spinner.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            String output = new SendRequest().execute().get();      
            spinner.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);           
         }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("buttonClickHandler exception: "+ex);
         }
      }
  }
```

and AsyncTask class is:

```
  public class SendRequestExample extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, String> {
      public String result; 

          protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {

              // doing communication 
              ...

              return result;
          }      
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should show your progress bar in :

```
SendRequestExample.onPreExecute()
```

and hide it in:

```
SendRequestExample.onPostExecute()
```

methods.

If your SendRequestExample is universal for many activities, then you can make MyActivity  implement interface, ie:

```
interface ProgressBarAware {
  void showProgressbar();
  void hideProgressbar();
}
```

and pass ProgressBarAware reference to your AsyncTask. Its important to update this reference in AsyncTask during configuration changes, that means every time your Activity.onCreate executes after config change.

---

One more: dont use get() on asynctask on UI thread, in call 'new SendRequest().execute().get();'. This causes lots of problems. It block message queue that is used by Android to process messages responsible for reacting to user clicks, drawing widgets, and lots more. After few minutes, such UI thread blocking will end up in ANR (Application Is Not Responding), and system will terminate your app.

Comment: ProgressBar is in my_activity_layout. How should i access that. Accessing by findViewById didn't help. it doesn't show or hide ProgressBar. I tried it before

Comment: SO all activities in app will implement ProgressBarAware?

Comment: If you progressbar is in layout then I suppose you have no other choice. You can create base activity class for all your acitivities. Also, very often AsyncTasks are used to return some data to your activity, such interface is quite usefull then.

Comment: I think I have given you all the hints. One more: dont use get() on asynctask on UI thread, in call 'new SendRequest().execute().get();'. This causes lots of problems.

Comment: You are right problem is that i am calling execute.get(). But without that i can't string from AsyncTask. It means that i need to AsyncTask in my every activity where i am using it. its will be a lot of repetition of code.

Comment: Please write you comment as answer so i accept it. Thanks for help.

Comment: I have addd this comment to anwer, with extra informations.

Answer (score 1):

`Every activity of my class uses this AsyncTask class for communication`

Use ProgressDialog inside AsyncTask

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog ;


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        m_logger.d("onPreExecute");
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(m_applicationContext);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
                ....
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Intent result) 
    {
        if( null != pDialog)
            pDialog.dismiss();
        .....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to declare `ProgressDialog` inside the `Activity(s)` itself. instead you can create `ProgressDialog` inside `AsyncTask` like this.

```
public class SendRequestExample extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdialog = new ProgressDialog(yourcontexthere);
    ....
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pdialog.setTitle("Please wait.");
        pdialog.setMessage("doing stuff...");
        pdialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         // doing stuff
        ...
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(pdialog.isShowing())
            pdialog.dismiss();
        ...
    }       
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this too but app freezes and when it unfreezes then it shows dialog and hide it

Comment: i have used it dozens of times and always works perfectly for me. i dont know what may be wrong with it.

Comment: My app freezes and show dialog for just before it is unfreezed. But i have logs in onPreExecute. They are shown on time but dialog does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Hide your ProgressBar in the XML and follow the below steps.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressBar bar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    new MyTask().execute();
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

}
```